# Algorithms: Using maximum flow to calculate correct matrix values

Tags: algorithm, networking, optimization, matrix, graph-theory

I am given an matrix A with size N x M with `N,M <= 100`. Matrix A consists of integer values A(i,j) where i and j are  `0 < i < M` and `0 < j < N`. I am also given the "correct" column sums and row sums of the matrix. The given values A(i,j) are "incorrect" (they do not match the "correct" sums) and therefore we are provided with corresponding "incorrectness" values B(i,j), where B(i,j) ranges from 0 to A(i,j).

The goal is to calculate the "correct" values C(i,j) in the matrix, where `A(i,j) - C(i,j) =< B(i,j)`, the C(i,j) values must also match the given row and column sums.  I think I have to use maximum flow, but my attempts have not worked. How can I achieve this?

Comment: If this is from some online judge, can you provide the link to the problem?

Comment: The page is in Dutch, sadly.

Comment: Is this from an ongoing contest? And what's the precise relationship between A and B?

Comment: You're right; see my edits. It's not ongoing - I am just trying to practice.

Comment: What makes you think a network flow model is suitable for this? What about dynamic programming?

Comment: It's one of the hints in the description of the problem. @Codor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just give you an example here.

```
matrix A:
 10 10 10
 10 10 10
 10 10 10

matrix B:
  2  3  4
  5  6  4
  3  2  1

matrix A-B:
  8  7  6
  5  4  6
  7  8  9
```

So you have the formula A[i,j] - C[i,j] <= B[i,j]. You can transform it into A[i,j] - B[i,j] <= C[i,j] which means that B[i,j] is the smallest thing that you need to subtract from A[i,j] to get something smaller or equal to C[i,j]. From here you know that you need to add something to the entries in matrix A-B.

Let's now find what and where to add.

Let's assume you are given the following row and column sizes:

```
c1 = 20/20
c2 = 19/21
c3 = 21/24

r1 = 21/21
r2 = 15/17
r3 = 24/27
```

Above I wrote things in the form of:

```
(current flow through column or row) / (goal flow through column or row).
```

Now let's build a network:

[image: network]

Now note that the total sum of rows = total sum of columns. So you try to push 'given sum of entries' - 'current sum of entries' from 's' to 't'.

Now, let's assume that the nodes are enumerated from left to right by natural numbers. Now, when you push something from a second level node to a third level node, say, you push something from node i, to node j, you also add whatever you pushed to NewMatrix[i,j], where NewMatrix is the matrix A-B and you get the matrix you want.

Also note that in the beginning, in the matrix A-B, you had the smallest C[i,j] that you had to subtract from A[i,j] to get something smaller or equal to B[i,j], and now that you added something to that C[i,j] the inequality A[i,j]-C[i,j]<=B[i,j] still holds.

Comment: Thank you very much. You have cleared things up for me, but I do not quite understand what you mean in the last two paragraphs. If I solve this graph using maximum flow I would find one number I think, what would that number then mean?

Comment: @user1760791 the nodes in the graph on the second level represent columns, and in the third level rows. If you can push flow through c_i to r_j and then to t, then you can add that amount of flow in location NewMatrix[i,j]. Get it? More intuitively: if you know that you need the sum to be x units bigger in the column i, and y units bigger in the row j, then you can add min(x,y) at location NewMatrix[i,j] without making the matrix invalid.

Comment: @user1760791 also, this is kind of a matching problem.

Comment: oops. i mean, the second level is rows and third level is columns, but it shouldnt matter, i guess.

Comment: Your solution seems to be working for me with 2D matrices, if I try bigger ones it seems to fail (the x (sum difference) will be much to large if there's more than 2 numbers and too much will be added to the first numbers in NewMatrix). Maybe I am misunderstanding it? Thank you!

Comment: @user1760791 what do you mean by "bigger than 2D matrices"? that doesn't make sense. If the numbers are large, use biginteger?

Comment: Wait, I'm mistaken, sorry. By bigger I mean more dimensions. But the reason I gave in the above comment is wrong. It might be a mistake in my implementation (C# code).

Comment: @user1760791 in your question you only talk about 2D matrices, N by M.

Comment: However, it's simple to transform this solution into 3d etc case.

Comment: Ok - now it's going wrong for me in a 2D matrix as well. It computes all rows and columns sums correctly, except the last one, C[m,n], because it adds values too early. This is what I have so far: http://pastebin.com/NuWVeLuP